# Custom Navigation drawer with radio buttons and checkboxes

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer

I want to create a custom navigation drawer with textviews, radio buttons and checkboxes. And when i check the radiobuttons and chckboxes some text has to be displayed. I searched on several sites but none was relevant.

All i saw was creating string arrays and then displaying them as a listview in nav drawer.

I need some suggestions or ideas to implement this.

Comment: There's nothing really special about the ListView commonly used in a Navigation Drawer. You can replace it with whatever container View you want. Just make sure you've got the `layout_gravity` set correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I have a simple answer for this.

First define your items in the list in `strings.xml`

```
<string-array name="titles">
    <item>Hotel</item>
    <item>Historical Sites</item>
    <item>Shopping</item>
    <item>Restaurant</item>
    <item>Attractions</item>
    <item>wild Life</item>
    <item>Tour Service</item>
</string-array>
```

Then add a list view to your mainmenu

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<!-- Listview to display slider menu -->
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/slider_list"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
```

Then create `list_item.xml`

add following code their.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:padding="5dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

After properly code `mainmenu.java` (You should probably know this)you can have what you need.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to customize you Adapter class by extending BaseAdapter and Override necessary Methods

   @Override
   public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2)
   {

   }
2. There many Tutorial  in web as well as code Snippet in StackOverFlow